# Proof that $[\alpha, \infty)$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

I'm wondering if my approach to this proof is correct. Would appreciate your evaluation.

**Prove** that $[\alpha, \infty)$ is closed for all $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$.

**Proof**

> We need to show that $[\alpha, \infty)^c=(-\infty, \alpha)$ $(*)$ is open. Let $x \in *$, $\varepsilon:=\lvert x - \alpha\lvert$. Pick a $y\in B_\varepsilon(x)$ so that $\lvert y-x\lvert<\varepsilon$. We need to show that $\lvert y-\alpha\lvert<2\lvert x-\alpha\lvert$.
>   Now, $\lvert y - \alpha\lvert=\lvert y -x+x-\alpha\lvert\le \lvert y-x \lvert+\lvert x-\alpha\lvert<\varepsilon+\lvert x-\alpha\lvert=2\varepsilon$.
>   Hence, $y\in B_\varepsilon(x)\implies y\in[\alpha, \infty)^c\implies[\alpha,\infty)^c$ is open, and $[\alpha, \infty)$ is closed.

Comment: "We need to show that $∣y−\alpha∣<2∣x−\alpha∣$": I don't get this. I would say we need to show that $∣y−\alpha∣<∣x−\alpha∣$. (Also, you know that $x < \alpha$, so it's clearer to set $\varepsilon = \alpha - x$.)

Comment: $2\lvert x-\alpha\lvert$ is coming from the need to ensure that $y\in B_\varepsilon(x)$. I agree that your proof is simpler.

Comment: Since $\varepsilon$ is chosen to be $\lvert x-\alpha \lvert$, it is the radius of $B_\varepsilon(x)$, and we need to ensure that $y$ is in this open ball centered at $x$. Since $y$ can be to the left or to the right of $x$, to ensure that $y$ is in this open ball, we need to ensure that $y < 2\lvert x - \alpha\lvert$, since this is basically the diameter of the open ball.

Comment: 1) You don't want to show that y is within a diameter distance to be in a ball; you want to show that it is in radius distance. 2) you don't want to show y is in a ball around *alpha* because half of the points around alpha are larger than alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be a little confused about what exactly you need to show. Here is my own proof along similar lines.

> We need to show that $[\alpha,\infty)^\mathsf{c}=(-\infty,\alpha)=I$ is open. Let $x\in I$, and let $\epsilon=\alpha-x$. If $y\in B_{\epsilon}(x)=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$, we then have $y<x+\epsilon$, that is, $y<x+\alpha-x=\alpha$. Hence $y\in I$ whenever $y\in B_{\epsilon}(x)$. Since this argument holds for all $x\in I$, it follows that $I$ is open, and hence that $[\alpha,\infty)$ is closed.

Some extra advice:

- You are always free to refer to equations by symbols such as $(\ast)$, but you should really avoid calling things like numbers and sets anything like $(\ast)$. In particular, "$x\in\ast$" is highly unusual, and I actually found it quite jarring to read.
- Were I actually asked such a question, I would not use this definition of "closed" to answer it. Rather, I would use the sandwich/squeeze theorem for sequences in conjunction with the following theorem (which hopefully is familiar to you):

  > A subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ (for any $d\in\mathbb{N}$) is closed if and only if every convergent sequence $(x_{n})$ contained in $A$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n} \in A$.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, even though it's more complicated, I'm showing that since $\varepsilon$ is chosen to be $\lvert x-\alpha \lvert$, it is the radius of $B_\varepsilon(x)$, and we need to ensure that $y$ is in this open ball centered at $x$. Since $y$ can be to the left or to the right of $x$, to ensure that $y$ is in this open ball, we need to ensure that $y < 2\lvert x - \alpha\lvert$, since this is basically the diameter of the open ball.

Comment: But you *chose* y to be in that ball.  You don't choose it to be in a ball and then prove if it is in the ball.  And be *increasing* the radius we don't make it *more* likely to be in the ball; we make it *less* likely because you just created a ball that is twice as big.  Showing that something is in a *big* ball doesn't mean that it is in the small ball.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subseteq(-\infty,\alpha)$, where $\epsilon=\alpha-x$ (it is the convenient choice). Take $y\in(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. We have $y<x+\epsilon=x+(\alpha-x)=\alpha$. So $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subseteq(-\infty,\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple proof which does not need to use complements:

Let $ x \notin [\alpha,\infty) $. Then $x < \alpha$. Let $\delta = |x-\alpha|$. Then the open ball $B_{\delta} (x)$ centred at $x$ will not intersect $[\alpha,\infty)$, therefore $x$ is not a limit point of $[\alpha,\infty)$. This is equivalent to the statement that if $x$ is a limit point of $[\alpha,\infty)$ , then  $ x \in [\alpha,\infty) $, which is the same as saying that $[\alpha,\infty)$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track but you logic and continuity are off.

Revision first, critique later.

I'm trying to rewrite your proof in your style and reasoning as much as possible:

=====

We need to show that $[\alpha,\infty)^c=(−\infty,\alpha)(∗)$ is open. Let $x \in ∗, \epsilon :=∣x−\alpha∣$. We need to show that $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset *$. Pick a $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x)$ so that $∣y−x∣<\epsilon$. We need to show that $y \in *$. Now $|y - x|< \epsilon \implies y \in (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \implies y < x + \epsilon = x + \alpha - x = \alpha \implies y \in (-\infty, \alpha) = *$. Hence, $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x) \implies y \in [\alpha, \infty)^c \implies [\alpha, \infty)^c$ is open $\implies  [\alpha, \infty)$ is closed.

=====

Now critique of what you wrote:

We need to show $(-\infty, \alpha) = (*)$ is open.  check.  Let $x \in (*);$ let $\epsilon = |\alpha - x|$. Check.

Let $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x)$.  Okay... but....

1) You should state this point that our goal is to show $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset (*)$.  It's not clear from the rest of the proof that you are aware that this is the goal.

2) We should state that our goal is to show $y \in (*)$.  As $y$ is arbitrary that means $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset (*)$ and as $x$ was arbitrary that'd imply (*) is open.

3) You claim to show instead that $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x)$ which is a) unnecessary as we just declared that to be true in the first place b) doesn't in anyway show that $(*)$ is open and ... c) well... your argument isn't actually correct.

Then you claim the we need to show that $|y - a| < 2|x - a|$.  This is where your proof goes off the rails.  Showing that gives us no information.  Let $x = -1; \alpha = 0$ and $y = 1/2$.  Then $|y -\alpha | < 2|x - a|$ in fact $|y - a| < |x - \alpha|$.  But $y \not \in (*)$.

What we need to show is that $y \in (*)$.

Then you show correctly show that $|y - a| < 2\epsilon$ and a conclude that that implies $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x)$.

1) We didn't need to show that as we declared it when we chose $y$ and

2) It doesn't show that; it shows $y \in B_{2\epsilon}(\alpha)$ which may or may not have anything to do with $B_{\epsilon}(x)$.

Then you conclude $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x) \implies (*)$ is open.  It only implies that if we can show $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset (*)$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out these important peculiarities in a rather detailed response.